# To identify special characters in a column in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, null, special-characters

From the below sample data, I need to identify bank accounts which contain 'NULL' or values which contain special characters like . and +.

Please help with SQL query.

```
Country code        Country no.
CN                  1.41601002200003E+16
KR                  1081100499433
DK                  5005923427
GB                  20451053
CH                  86381881
SE                  51017374
CA                  101798545
AE                  90010200008612
AT                  NULL
US                  1134133639
BE                  220000422994
IT                  1264
CN                  1.1006058714634E+17
AT                  NULL
```

Comment: First of all datatype of that column. Second it looks like you have FLOAT or someone insert float into that column. Fix cause then data. `1.41601002200003E+16` -> `14160100220000300`

Comment: Thank you. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `like` with exclusive character sets:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.country_no like '%[^0-9]%' or t.country_no is null;
```

If the issue is simply that large numbers don't "look" right, then convert them to a string:

```
select str(t.country_no, 20)
from t
where t.country_no like '%[^0-9]%' or t.country_no is null;
```

Comment: You say **Use NOT LIKE** I think, No? mybe you mean escape